# Programmatically load and submit the user form

Tags: 7, forms

I want to programmatically load the user profile form for a particular user and re-submit it without changing any of the existing values. The reasons are complex but I am dependent on gathering data during the form submit phase.

I can see functions to build an empty form ( `drupal_get_form` ) and to submit a new form ( `drupal_form_submit` ), but I can't see how to load the form prepopulated with the correct `$form_state`.

Answer (score 1):

To load the user form with all data :

```
$user = $GLOBALS['user'];
$uid = $user->uid;
$account = user_load($uid);

$form = drupal_get_form("user_profile_form", $account);
```

But you need to include page handler first

```
    // Include page handler for node_add()
    module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');
```

So your code will be:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');
$user = $GLOBALS['user'];
$uid = $user->uid;
$account = user_load($uid);

$form = drupal_get_form("user_profile_form", $account);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to prepoulate value of any form programmatically & submit like this

`$form_state = array();
$form_id = 'invite_form';
$form_state['values']['email'] = 'abc@xyz.com';
drupal_form_submit($form_id, $form_state);`

If you want to gather data during user save as mention in question use [hook_user_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7).

Comment: Thanks Rupesh but my requirement is to submit the user profile form with all the existing values in place just as if I'd gone to user/1/edit ( say ) and immediately clicked on submit.

Comment: For profile which module you used ?

Comment: Just Drupal 7's ability to add fields to user objects.